# Manga where a prince gets banished from a kingdom and his sisters go looking for him

Tags: story-identification, manga

Looking for a specific manga where there is a kingdom that’s all about power and skills.

The king has 3 kids. The son of the king ends up not having any power so he is exiled. When his sisters get back from a mission they are on they realize he’s missing and they go looking for him.

Answer (score 4):

[*Ane ga Kensei de Imouto ga Kenja de*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/129402/Ane_ga_Kensei_de_Imouto_ga_Kenja_de) (My Older Sister is Kensei and My Little Sister is a Wise Man)

> Born as the son of a king of such a country, Razel had only human talent in swords and magic. However, his elder sister was a genius who was called Kensei (Sword Saint), and his little sister was a genius who was called a Wise Man (Sage).
>
> Compared to such older sister and little sister, he was finally banished from the country as he had no talent. However, Razel had a positive attitude and aimed for a different country to live freely as an adventurer.
>
> Following Razel, even his sister Kensei and his sister Sage left the country to follow Razel: "If Razel was expelled of the country then there 's no meaning stay here any no longer.
>
> <sub><sup>(per [NovelUpdates.com](https://forum.novelupdates.com/threads/my-older-sister-is-kensei-and-my-little-sister-is-a-wise-man.123770/)</sup></sub>

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you add a description of this in case the link breaks sometime in the future?

Comment: Please don't add copyright infringing links.